# How to search and replace long HTML in multiple files on Linux

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I need to recursively find all files with this HTML:

```
<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

And replace it with this HTML:

```
<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt of a grep command piped to a sed:

```
grep --include="index.html" -PRwzl -e '<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">\n' | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">\n/<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">\n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">\n/g' @
```

The grep command alone works perfectly.

For clarity, here is the command split into many sections.:

```
grep --include="index.html" \
    -PRwzl \
    -e '<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
        \n    <meta charset="utf-8">
        \n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
        \n' \
    | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
                            \n    <meta charset="utf-8">
                            \n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
                            \n
                        /<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
                            \n    <meta charset="utf-8">
                            \n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
                            \n    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
                            \n    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
                            \n    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
                            \n    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
                            \n    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
                            \n
                        /g' @
```

Comment: Your attempt is a `grep` command which you claim is unsuccessful but works perfectly?  Clarify.

Comment: @Nic3500 My attempt is a grep command piped to a sed command. The grep command alone works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is very complex for nothing.  You can run your `sed` on the file, without the `grep` and `xargs` before.  Typically an inline edit of a file with `sed` looks like:

```
sed -i 's/TO_FIND/REPLACE/' FILE.txt
```

Another comment, `sed` is not a great tool to edit HTML.  Look at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

That being said I propose this script to meet your requirement.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
find . -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    if [[ $(grep -c 'id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"' $file) -ne 0 ]]
    then
        # Add the content...
        echo "Adding in file $file"
        sed -i 's#</head>#    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">\n    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">\n    </head>#' "$file"
    else
        echo "Nothing to do on $file"
    fi
done
```

- Using `find` with `while` and `read` cover cases where you have HTML files in sub-directories.
- The `grep` has been highly simplified.  If the id and class values are present, it is enough to identify valid files.
- Then in the `sed`, you can just add the new lines.  Your `sed` replaced lines with these same lines.
- I used `#` as a separator in `sed` instead of `/` to avoid confusion with HTML code.
- This is based on a file I created myself, since you did not provide a sample.  You should provide samples in your questions.
- The order of tags within the `<head>` section is not relevant, so adding lines just before the closing `</head>` works.
- Obviously the `else` section is optional.
- `<opinion>`I find this type of script easier to understand and debug in the future than long single liners.`</opinion>`.

Assuming that index.html is:

```
<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <title>TITRE</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <p>PARAGRAPH</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<html id="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52-000000001" class="blx-5fb3c619e82a2863d6567c52"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <title>TITRE</title>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>PARAGRAPH</p>
    </body>
</html>
```